# I am encountering an error on Julia while trying to install and use Distributions module

Tags: julia

I am encountering an error on Julia while trying to install and use Distributions module. I am not facing any errors while installing the module but it displays this error when I try to use the Distributions module. I have no idea what this PDMats or Manifest files are. I'd love to have some advice. Thanks!

This is the entire error:

```
julia> using Distributions
 │ Package Distributions not found, but a package named Distributions is available from a registry. 
 │ Install package?
 │   (@v1.7) pkg> add Distributions 
 └ (y/n) [y]: y
    Updating registry at `C:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.julia\registries\General.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
    Updating `C:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.julia\environments\v1.7\Project.toml`
  [31c24e10] + Distributions v0.21.12
  No Changes to `C:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.julia\environments\v1.7\Manifest.toml`
[ Info: Precompiling Distributions [31c24e10-a181-5473-b8eb-7969acd0382f]
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package PDMats does not have IterativeEigensolvers in its dependencies:
- If you have PDMats checked out for development and have
  added IterativeEigensolvers as a dependency but haven't updated your primary
  environment's manifest file, try `Pkg.resolve()`.
- Otherwise you may need to report an issue with PDMats
Stacktrace:
 [1] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:980
 [2] include
   @ .\Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [3] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1318
 [4] top-level scope
   @ none:1
 [5] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [6] eval(x::Expr)
   @ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:453
 [7] top-level scope
   @ none:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.julia\packages\PDMats\jTYWO\src\PDMats.jl:3
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile PDMats [90014a1f-27ba-587c-ab20-58faa44d9150] to C:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.julia\compiled\v1.7\PDMats\jl_565F.tmp.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base .\error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:997
  [7] include
    @ .\Base.jl:418 [inlined]
  [8] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::Nothing)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1318
  [9] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [10] eval
    @ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [11] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:453
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.julia\packages\Distributions\KjaXI\src\Distributions.jl:1
ERROR: Failed to precompile Distributions [31c24e10-a181-5473-b8eb-7969acd0382f] to C:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.julia\compiled\v1.7\Distributions\jl_52F6.tmp.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base .\error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:997
  [7] eval
    @ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
  [8] eval
    @ .\Base.jl:68 [inlined]
  [9] repleval(m::Module, code::Expr, #unused#::String)
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\repl.jl:157
 [10] (::VSCodeServer.var"#78#80"{Module, Expr, REPL.LineEditREPL, REPL.LineEdit.Prompt})()
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\repl.jl:123
 [11] with_logstate(f::Function, logstate::Any)
    @ Base.CoreLogging .\logging.jl:511
 [12] with_logger
    @ .\logging.jl:623 [inlined]
 [13] (::VSCodeServer.var"#77#79"{Module, Expr, REPL.LineEditREPL, REPL.LineEdit.Prompt})()
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\repl.jl:124
 [14] #invokelatest#2
    @ .\essentials.jl:716 [inlined]
 [15] invokelatest(::Any)
    @ Base .\essentials.jl:714
 [16] macro expansion
    @ c:\Users\rajaissacsamuel.k\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:34 [inlined]   
 [17] (::VSCodeServer.var"#60#61")()
    @ VSCodeServer .\task.jl:423
```

Comment: try `Pkg.resolve()`, if that fails try resetting the Julia registry

Comment: @SanidhyaSingh Thank you, I got it fixed through ```Pkg.update()```

Answer (score 0):

try `Pkg.resolve()` or `Pkg.update()`, if that fails try resetting the Julia registry